# Gentle synonym for stupid

Tags: word-request, synonyms, politeness

How you can express that you felt stupid for a thing you told but without using the term "stupid", like in a nicer manner?

For example:

She felt "stupid" for the things she told to her friend.

Comment: Silly, childlike, immature ?

Comment: There are lots of possible words. Please help us to suggest the right word by editing your question to explain what exactly was wrong with telling her friend. Was it untrue or ill-informed? Was it unkind? Was she too trusting, telling her friend something that could be used to damage her?

Comment: i think most synonyms for stupid tend to be fairly harsh, at least in certain contexts or with different tone of voice. Silly, childlike, or immature can all actually be very insulting as descriptors, especially if it’s been a point of contention before between people.

Comment: How about *unsophisticated*?

Answer (score 2):

As per the comments, I feel “silly” is a bit lighter.

You could try something more emotionally specific/descriptive, such as “embarrassed” or “guilty”.

You could also prefix anything you say with “a bit” or “a little” to tone it down and make it sound less harsh.

> She felt a bit stupid/silly.

Answer (score 0):

"Foolish" would be a slightly more sophisticated word to use.